# EditText underline color styling

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-view, android-theme, android-styles

I have a problem, I know that the underline in Lollipop is styled by `colorControlNormal`, so I have set it inside my styles-v21 like:

```
<item name="colorControlNormal">?android:textColorSecondary</item>
```

and then in my style for `EditText` I have set

```
<item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/color_green</item>
```

However this does not work, it works when I change it inside my style to

```
<item name="colorControlNormal">@color/color_green</item>
```

But thats not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

> I know that the underline (of `EditText`) in Lollipop is styled by `colorControlNormal`

That's not true, it's controlled by `colorAccent` attribute.

Create your custom theme:

```
<style name="MyCustomTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="colorAccent">#00FF00</item>
</style>
```

And then apply this theme to your `EditText` in the xml:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="matc_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/MyCustomTheme"/>
```

You'll get this output:

[image]